# Laravel - Constant expression contains invalid operations in Select distinct

Tags: laravel

I am writing a Query in Laravel as Select distinct:

```
protected static $type = DB::table('customers')->distinct('region')->get();
```

The column, region should be distinct.

I want to utilize it in:

```
        $revenuedetails = DB::table('customers as g')
    ->select(
       DB::raw('DATE(g.created_at) as created_date'),
       'g.msisdn', 
       'g.region', 
       'g.amount'              
  )
 ->whereRaw('g.region' , self::$type[$region] ?? null)
```

as a where clause parameter, but I got this error:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
>   Constant expression contains invalid operations

How do I resolve this?

Comment: You can add function calls to property definitions which is why you're getting this error. Are you using Eloquent at all in your application? Also, is the above code from a controller?

Comment: The codes are from controller